# Regex Expression for capturing a starting and ending with a group of characters

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

I've been looking for an answer for quite a while, and i can't find it anywhere else, so I'm posting over here. I need a regex for capturing this form of expression `{{{any_Name}}}`. I'm looking towards capturing the starting 3 `{{{` and the ending 3 `}}}`.

I can capture the first three with the expression `\{{3}/g`. But i can't figure out how to catch the last 3 `}}}`

Comment: Doesn't `\}{3}` do it? Why do you think it's any different from matching the starting `{{{`?

Comment: No It doesn't, I've tried it.

Comment: I don't believe you. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: ```(\{{3})(\}{3})```  doesn't work

Comment: Of coursse not, because that doesn't match the characters in between the starting and ending braces.

Comment: That will match `{{{}}}` with nothing between them.

Comment: Okay, so it will only accept ```{{{}}}``` only!

Comment: Add the pattern for the middle part and it will accept what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
\{{3}[^{}]+}{3}
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/5L6WlauvcxQoHN).

This matches:

- `\{{3}` is `{{{`
- `[^{}]+` is "one or more non-brackets"
- `}{3}` is `}}}`

Note that `}` does not need escaping.

Comment: Thorough and a detailed answer, my concepts are clear now. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the kind of text in {} is still the same (alphanumeric + _), you can simply use something like that :

```
\{{3}\w+\}{3}
```

So you catch any expression starting with 3 {, then contening letters, numbers or _ and ended by 3 }.

Comment: Use `\w` for alphanumeric.

Comment: https://regexr.com/6001v Have tried over here didn't work.

Comment: remove the # there where only here to delimit the regex XD https://regexr.com/60022

Comment: Why do you have `#` delimiter? That's only need in some languages, it's not part of the regexp itself.

Comment: PHP habit I belive, sorry :p As i needed the i flag in the first regex. But you're right I will edit my post without.